# Poisson xgboost with exposure

Tags: r, caret, poisson-regression, offset, boosting

I was trying to model a count dependent variable with uneven exposure. Classical glms would use log(exposure) as offset, also gbm does, but xgboost does not allow for offset until now...

Trying to find a drawback this example in crossvalidated ([Where does the offset go in Poisson/negative binomial regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66791/where-does-the-offset-go-in-poisson-negative-binomial-regression)) suggested me to model frequency (real number) instead of counts weighting by Exposure.

I tried to work aroung some xgboost code to apply the same method on my data but I failed.... Below the code I set out:

```
library(MASS)
data(Insurance)
library(xgboost)
options(contrasts=c("contr.treatment","contr.treatment")) #fissa i 

Insurance$freq<-with(Insurance, Claims/Holders )
library(caret)

temp<-dplyr::select(Insurance,District, Group, Age,freq)
temp2= dummyVars(freq ~ ., data = temp, fullRank = TRUE) %>% predict(temp)

xgbMatrix <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(temp2), 
                     label = Insurance$freq, 
                     weight = Insurance$Holders)

bst = xgboost(data=xgbMatrix, label = Insurance$freq,    objective='count:poisson',nrounds=5)
#In xgb.get.DMatrix(data, label) : xgboost: label will be ignored. 
#strange warning

Insurance$predFreq<-predict(bst, xgbMatrix)

with(Insurance, sum(Claims)) #3151
with(Insurance, sum(predFreq*Holders)) #7127 fails
```

Can anybody help? Also, I was wondering if It were possible to run all using caret's train...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the answer in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896004/xgboost-offset-exposure

`xgboost` can handle `offset` term as in `glm` or `gbm` using `setinfo`, but this method is not documented very well.

In your example, the code would be:

    `setinfo(xgbMatrix,"base_margin",log(Insurance$Holders))`

Answer (score 4):

Your code works just fine, you just need to increase the parameter nround to have the desired result. The Boosting models don't converge at the first iterations.

```
xgbMatrix <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(temp2), 
                         label = Insurance$freq,
                         weight = Insurance$Holders)

bst = xgboost(data=xgbMatrix, objective='count:poisson', nrounds=500, verbose = 0)

Insurance$predFreq<-predict(bst, xgbMatrix)

with(Insurance, sum(Claims)) #3151
with(Insurance, sum(predFreq*Holders)) #same
```