# Predict function on negative binomial produces strange fitted values when adding an offset

Tags: r, predictive-models, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, offset

I have an over-dispersed count dataset and I want to add an offset to my negative binomial on the RHS to create a rate of events for `y` (see [this great answer for further explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66791/where-does-the-offset-go-in-poisson-negative-binomial-regression)). Next, I want to create a predicted plot of my results.

However, after following examples from smarter folks than myself, I get strange fitted values from the `predict()` function depending on where I put the offset on in my model.

Here's my example:

```
library(MASS)

y <- c(0,0,20,28,20,24,8,8,4,9,0,4,0,35,3,8,4,5,7,10,19,21,19,2,0,12,32,5,1,1,1,16,1,13,7,6,7,1,7,6,8,9,13,37,17,2,2,1,5,1,2,6,8,9,3,15,6,1,7,0,1,0,11,0,4,12,3,36,2,0,1,8,4,3,25,12,4,2,20,2,24,5,25,2,8,1,1,6,29,50,14,12,7,40,1,0,1,0,1,12,0,1,0,1,1,4,3,1,13,6,2,4,19,3,8,4,5,10,46,4,1,45,4,4,4,2,9,8,43,3,1,22,5,10,1,4,0,17,4,5,3,3,1,28,32,1,9,1,4,27,7,9,23,1,4,19,1,1,2,3,2,6,11,2,54,7,19,22,23,18,27,4,2,3,2,16,5,19,16,8,9,2,8,2,18,2,6,16,13,6,4,7,40,6,16,5,12,17,0,1,6,40,93,16,6,19,6,8,31,1,4,0,17,3,6,13,23,9,12,7,8,2,14,16,15,28,3,20,35,16,5,7,2,51,6,1,17,2,13,19,13,18,1,5,13,7,0,10,11,21,15,0,31,17,8,2,5,1,3,59,9,3,9,1,2,0,35,5,6,2,2,7,9,34,1,32,8,2,9,0,2,0,4,33,36,13,44,4,17,2,0,0,9,15,14,19,1,11,16,80,8,29,3,18,20,7,6,10,14,54,9,25,4,22,9,16,2,7,7,41,11,4,32,4,16,7,6,51,7,9,8,7,19,82,4,43,3,7,17,53,24,12,23,82,5,10,16,57,9,8,3,16,20,37,4,29,15,11,13,16,4,54,0,8,10,28,53,7,6,23,0,48,11,21,38,4,6,18,13,9,6,17,17,15,83,15,3,17,8,44,6,43,13,67,47,14,11)
x <- c(-35.93,-35.81,-33.93,-33.56,-32.87,-32.11,-31.47,-31.29,-31.27,-30.76,-30.54,-29.65,-29.39,-29.06,-28.99,-28.50,-28.16,-26.72,-25.60,-24.83,-24.29,-24.24,-23.07,-22.92,-22.72,-22.68,-22.53,-22.42,-22.25,-22.08,-21.86,-21.61,-21.45,-21.35,-21.33,-21.16,-20.70,-20.52,-20.35,-20.27,-20.18,-20.14,-19.96,-19.89,-19.89,-19.01,-18.83,-18.68,-18.54,-18.51,-18.16,-17.96,-17.91,-17.80,-17.67,-17.54,-17.35,-17.23,-16.92,-16.79,-16.74,-16.63,-16.59,-16.59,-16.33,-16.33,-16.20,-15.92,-15.61,-15.51,-15.32,-15.30,-15.29,-15.24,-15.09,-15.05,-14.96,-14.69,-14.56,-13.92,-13.82,-13.79,-13.79,-13.71,-13.65,-13.51,-12.90,-12.73,-12.66,-12.51,-12.48,-12.36,-12.32,-12.30,-12.19,-12.18,-12.17,-11.87,-11.82,-11.60,-11.52,-11.36,-11.04,-10.97,-10.91,-10.75,-10.75,-10.52,-10.45,-10.44,-10.22,-10.19,-10.15,-9.95,-9.92,-9.68,-9.59,-9.18,-8.92,-8.68,-8.33,-8.28,-8.25,-8.02,-8.00,-7.98,-7.97,-7.87,-7.84,-7.68,-7.55,-7.50,-7.25,-7.14,-6.96,-6.74,-6.34,-6.33,-6.10,-6.03,-5.86,-5.83,-5.81,-5.81,-5.79,-5.76,-5.67,-5.35,-5.27,-5.21,-5.19,-5.15,-4.98,-4.77,-4.61,-4.30,-4.20,-4.07,-4.05,-4.00,-3.97,-3.94,-3.82,-3.75,-3.75,-3.65,-3.50,-3.44,-3.27,-3.17,-3.16,-2.77,-2.58,-2.36,-2.34,-2.30,-2.30,-2.29,-1.92,-1.86,-1.82,-1.75,-1.66,-1.56,-1.52,-1.45,-1.23,-1.22,-1.15,-0.89,-0.71,-0.70,-0.63,-0.56,-0.48,-0.47,-0.37,-0.31, 0.00, 0.02, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.12, 0.12, 0.21, 0.22, 0.41, 0.57, 0.59, 1.05, 1.14, 1.19, 1.33, 1.36, 1.40, 1.42, 1.43, 1.43, 1.68, 1.68, 1.80, 1.88, 1.89, 1.90, 1.99, 2.09, 2.09, 2.14, 2.27, 2.27, 2.32, 2.40, 2.64, 2.67, 2.78, 3.01, 3.02, 3.23, 3.25, 3.33, 3.40, 3.46, 3.47, 3.58, 3.62, 3.64, 3.66, 3.93, 4.02, 4.08, 4.19, 4.37, 4.53, 4.56, 4.61, 4.61, 4.69, 5.05, 5.14, 5.21, 5.58, 5.69, 5.70, 5.94, 6.12, 6.32, 6.33, 6.44, 6.50, 6.66, 6.83, 6.96, 7.17, 7.23, 7.41, 7.60, 7.62, 7.82, 7.86, 7.91, 7.91, 7.96, 8.09, 8.20, 8.31, 8.54, 8.55, 8.60, 8.66, 8.77, 8.84, 8.87, 8.92, 8.97, 9.13, 9.23, 9.34, 9.59, 9.75, 10.23, 10.26, 10.30, 10.32, 10.60, 10.66, 10.79, 10.94, 10.95, 11.31, 11.38, 11.49, 11.76, 11.82, 12.57, 12.61, 12.68, 12.80, 13.05, 13.10, 13.34, 13.52, 13.93, 14.04, 14.04, 14.67, 14.68, 14.72, 14.79, 14.97, 15.20, 15.53, 15.63, 15.92, 15.92, 15.99, 16.00, 16.12, 17.23, 17.35, 17.55, 17.61, 17.75, 17.77, 17.78, 17.83, 18.05, 18.09, 18.17, 18.20, 18.45, 18.61, 18.73, 18.96, 19.10, 19.53, 19.58, 19.65, 20.26, 20.52, 20.66, 20.96, 21.04, 21.05, 21.06, 21.36, 22.33, 22.54, 22.57, 22.94, 24.29, 24.38, 24.58, 24.58, 24.83, 24.95, 25.51, 25.70, 26.35, 27.13, 27.37, 28.29, 28.80, 28.93, 29.26, 29.29, 29.82, 31.25, 31.41, 32.77, 32.85, 33.36, 34.01, 34.60, 36.67, 37.56, 42.89)
z <- c(237,155,2523,960,2907,1972,531,353,238,1402,155,201,91,882,189,919,63,1322,447,384,2876,2025,778,347,248,1325,1658,419,247,193,138,1278,130,420,541,1341,935,111,1256,283,727,369,547,3322,719,253,372,481,949,390,247,789,1529,1086,594,735,479,186,828,342,1004,26,512,122,567,1270,269,959,214,94,303,302,349,129,1825,1157,882,740,284,358,894,296,449,1753,792,75,155,804,2206,4251,238,718,777,557,86,536,201,202,230,1105,451,211,667,92,603,175,304,110,429,408,531,289,174,349,320,1345,1320,785,1762,346,326,1222,300,309,591,380,907,649,840,212,318,854,463,737,138,503,264,799,416,808,323,530,822,2326,2484,86,628,347,342,640,386,1460,837,27,169,1147,312,1003,211,576,458,161,2649,1021,739,360,1111,1132,669,501,1182,174,124,653,1247,829,1008,1122,916,356,570,1387,712,211,993,54,347,1501,837,1695,157,767,909,1576,780,629,1213,1087,189,375,570,1393,843,2122,852,1141,1507,304,658,131,898,132,1123,136,1663,614,1318,710,343,639,954,217,652,755,813,1085,368,778,2715,923,1822,1081,130,1532,813,66,1563,661,1567,1056,473,891,175,472,696,1251,643,540,2693,973,959,103,952,595,408,110,486,400,1183,2324,607,353,300,246,298,222,1367,975,578,433,2344,403,3908,1640,750,1268,520,346,396,960,345,130,252,675,840,874,1029,237,1655,689,530,241,467,488,751,734,185,461,566,1372,1497,1216,848,1389,2170,423,1753,953,600,1267,1168,2950,163,1743,1804,2074,651,610,2775,2319,3970,469,874,626,1001,443,279,1580,665,783,1787,743,1462,1686,203,1375,1062,1742,1200,950,1674,871,853,1449,720,280,1670,1392,1938,639,570,1744,761,2645,126,1571,1293,1062,1524,1143,522,2098,363,553,1028,1652,1618,887,1521,1004,210,1175,366,756,1167,1137,243,1483,3727,611,1493,656,378,1498,2269,822,802,1655,1595,1515,979,1584,2448,1998,1525,602,2592)

data <- data.frame(y,x,z)
```

In the first model, I omit the offset, just for a baseline check. But this defeats the purpose of creating a rate interpretation:

```
m1 <- glm.nb(y ~ x, data=data)
```

The problem arises in the second model when I add the `offset(log(z))` inside the formula.

```
m2 <- glm.nb(y ~ x + offset(log(z)),data=data)
```

In fumbling around, I also moved the offset outside of the formula, but this converts the offset to a weights function across the whole model, where the `z` is now weighting across both `y` and `x`:

```
m3 <- glm.nb(y ~ x, offset(log(z)),data=data)
```

When I run the `predict()` function on these 3 models

```
pred <- cbind(data, "m1" = predict(m1, type="link", se.fit=TRUE)[1:2],
                "m2" = predict(m2, type="link", se.fit=TRUE)[1:2],
                "m3" = predict(m3, type="link", se.fit=TRUE)[1:2])
head(pred,10)

    y      x    z   m1.fit m1.se.fit   m2.fit  m2.se.fit   m3.fit  m3.se.fit
1   0 -35.93  237 1.860281 0.1347283 1.076164 0.11099828 1.983966 0.05165139
2   0 -35.81  155 1.862478 0.1343475 0.652252 0.11068868 1.985993 0.05150751
3  20 -33.93 2523 1.896910 0.1284076 3.453355 0.10585949 2.017758 0.04926325
4  28 -33.56  960 1.903686 0.1272450 2.489313 0.10491404 2.024009 0.04882388
5  20 -32.87 2907 1.916324 0.1250827 3.601413 0.10315558 2.035667 0.04800671
6  24 -32.11 1972 1.930243 0.1227105 3.217918 0.10122610 2.048508 0.04711008
7   8 -31.47  531 1.941964 0.1207209 1.909731 0.09960761 2.059322 0.04635798
8   8 -31.29  353 1.945261 0.1201627 1.502521 0.09915349 2.062363 0.04614696
9   4 -31.27  238 1.945627 0.1201008 1.108444 0.09910306 2.062701 0.04612352
10  9 -30.76 1402 1.954968 0.1185229 2.884901 0.09781922 2.071318 0.04552694
...
```

`m1.fit` and `m3.fit` have nice orderly fitted values, which plot nicely, while `m2.fit` is kind of random. In calculating the coefficients from `m2.fit` by hand, I don't get the same values at the given value of `x` either. I've spent many hours going over this problem and the data, simplifying down to this example. I'm not sure what's going on here. I have about 25 variables that I want to fit and this problem arises in all of them.

**Question:**

Can someone help me understand why model 2 is producing unordered fitted values when the formula includes the offset `y ~ x + offset(log(z))`? Are these not the predicted logged values of the rate of $log(y/z) = x$? I'm open to a better way of doing this too if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Are these not the predicted logged values of the rate?*

No, they're not. The predictions are for the expected frequency of events, not for the rate of events. The frequency of events obviously depends on $z$ as well as on $x$ and hence is not an ordered function of $x$ alone.

You don't explain what $z$ is in your data, but presumably it is the total population "at risk" size for each case.

To convert frequencies to rates you must divide by $z$. The only correct model is m2. To get the predicted rate, you need

```
PredictedRate <- exp(m2[,1]) / z
```

You will find that this is an increasing function of $x$:

```
plot(x, PredictedRate)
```

Note that model m1 is wrong because it doesn't incorporate the population at risk size ($z$) into your model. Model m3 is doubly wrong -- not only does it ignore $z$ in the fitted model but it specifies inappropriate weights. You should quickly abandon these models!

Comment: This makes complete sense, I will definitely abandon those other models. I can't thank you enough for the quick reply! You are correct, I am looking at renter evictions where `z = total renters` in a given tract and `y = evictions` for that tract. This study is examining the effects of neighborhood change on evictions where `x` is the median centered value for the given variable. Thank you!